# How to manage multiple staging branch (dev, stg and production branches) regarding PR integration?

Tags: git, github

I'm working on a team with multiple developers, all working on different things at the same time.
We have 3 general branches: dev, stg and master(production).
Each one of them has their own CI/CD server and are feeding a different environment.

The current flow for starting a new feature is:

1. Diverge out of master (production) a new feature branch
2. Develop locally and create commits.
3. Once ready and tested locally, push feature branch to remote, create PR and merge it into development branch.
4. Once confirmed to be working in the dev environment, open a PR to merge the feature branch to staging.
5. Once confirmed to be working in the stg environment, open a final PR to merge the feature branch to production and delete the feature branch.

This in my mind, shouldn't introduce any conflicts and allow multiple engineers to test multiple features in the development and staging environments, without pushing unfinished code to production.

The only code that's being pushed is from a feature branch that was already merged and tested in dev and staging, and not is being merged directly to master (production).

We avoid merging development > staging and staging > production because at any given moment, development can have changes we still don't want to merge to production.
So every developer shouldn't be affected by other developer's work.

The problem I am facing is I'm somehow, occasionally, create a PR to merge a feature branch to development branch, and then I see more "files changed" than what my feature branch is changing + many commits and I'm not sure where they are coming from.

My question is if our workflow is flawed and we should follow a different strategy.

Comment: It makes no sense to me to branch from master but merge into dev. Multiple long lived branches are bad enough without that sort of silliness. Do you understand what a Git merge is? Do you know what "merge base" means? (Also GitHub allows three different ways of accepting and closing a PR thru the merge button, and it makes a huge difference which one you use — but your question omits that info. Two of them are not actually merges at all, which can mean disaster with long lived branches.)

Comment: I understand what Git merge is and to be honest, I find your respond dis-respectful. If you are under the impression that I don't know what a Git Merge is you can either explain it or skip this question all together. To your question, the merge button in GitHub is currently configured to Allow all merge commits, squash merging and rebase merging.

Comment: "Best practice" type questions are generally off-topic here; consider softwareengineering.stackoverflow.com for such questions.

Comment: @snir.isl Sorry, but you have requested _opinions_. I'm happy to take mine away, but "eppur si muove." And sorry again, but if you knew what a merge is, you would not say "somehow, occasionally, create a PR to merge a feature branch to development branch, and then I see more "files changed" than what my feature branch is changing + many commits and I'm not sure where they are coming from". You would know _exactly_ where they are coming from.

Answer (score 1):

> The problem I am facing is I'm somehow, occasionally, create a PR to merge a feature branch to development branch, and then **I see more "files changed" than what my feature branch is changing** + many commits and I'm not sure where they are coming from.

This is a classic case of rebase --onto.

Whenever your PR shows too many commits, it means you need first:

- to fetch the remote tracking branches, refreshing the *target* branch (the branch your PR needs to be merged into)
- rebase your PR onto that refreshed remote tracking branch
- force push it again: that will update the PR which will show only your PR commits.

That is:

```sh
git fetch
git rebase --onto origin/dev my_feature_branch_first_commit~ my_feature_branch
```

Replace '`my_feature_branch_first_commit`' by the first commit of the feature branch, and don't forget the ~ (to select the parent of that first commit, since a rebase `--onto` move all commits *after* the first commit parameter)

If you know that first commit was done starting from another branch, you can replace '`my_feature_branch_first_commit`' with `$(git merge-base my_feature_branch another_branch)` (plus, again, the `~`)